# Prevent libsane.so.1 from being overwritten during update

Tags: linux, debian

I need to run the latest version of Sane-Backends to support my scanner.  I've compiled the source such that it's out of the way for the distro's package V1.22 but when I run an update it overwrites my simlink to libsane.so.1 so then  I have to manually update the symlink.

My Question is two fold:

1. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Should I pin the package?  I'm not sure if that's the correct approach?
2. If not is there some sort "hook" that I can connect a script to run on a post update action? ie run: `sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/libsane.so.1.0.24 libsane.so.1`

The OS is raspbian, aka Debian 7.0 for the Rasberry Pi.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. Unfortunately your question appears to be off topic as there's no obvious connection to professional system/network administration. You may wish to visit our sister sites [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se] to see if one of them may be a better fit for your question.

Comment: Didn't realize there was unix version.

Comment: Can you not just find an apt repo (eg backports) with the newer sane package there, and install from it?

Comment: Did you tried uupdate? A lot of times you can just build a newer version of a package with uupdate and the upstream tarball.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend compiling your source and keeping it separate from your system's libraries.  From there, you could do a couple of things:

- Copy the library file from the source directory into the folder of the binary you are executing

  - `cp /path/to/src/library.so /path/to/executable`

This assumes that the executable isn't "installed" and was a compressed file containing all of the libraries and binaries you would need.

- Add an environmental variable to **~/.bashrc** or **/etc/environment**

  - `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/source:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

It is important that this line is below other LD_LIBRARY_PATH lines.  The bottom should be fine.  If you put it into ~/.bashrc, only your user will be affected.  By placing it into /etc/environment, you'll make it a system-wide configuration.

In both cases, you're exploiting which library will be found first.  Programs *should* look in their local directory first for libraries.  They should also look through environmental paths in order.

Answer (score 0):

[CheckInstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) allows you to create packages for Debian that won't get overwritten. You use it something like this:

1. make sure you have all the dependencies you need. You can pull them in for the current version with something like `sudo apt-get build-dep sane-backends` (which pulls in the insanely large [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) system, which you likely don't need for anything else but building the docs.)
2. remove the system version of libsane with `sudo apt-get remove sane-backends` or similar.
3. Download, unpack and build the package as before, but instead of `make install`, do `sudo checkinstall`. It will prompt you for some input, then build a deb file that you can install.

As your own build has its own version number (and you don't have Debian's version to overwrite it) this should stick around for a while.